# SQL - reset cumulative value while keeping historical data

Tags: sql, triggers

I've been encharged, during my university internship, to create a web application to manage maintenace operations in the factory I work in. I'm an industrial engineer with just a little knowledge about database programming, so maybe this question will sound easy to you, I apologize.

That's the situation: the item is a mold, which needs ordinary maintenance after a number of operations (huge number, I'm talking about tiles manufacturing, and the maintenance frequency can be assumed as a mean value of once per year). I set up a database and the web application connected to it, and I created a view with the molds' list and the relative cumulative work, so that the department's responsible can have a fast perspective of the situation and see which molds need maintenance, and that works fine.

The problem is they "labeled" the molds, and I used that number as the row ID in the database. When the maintenance is performed the cumulative work needs to be resetted, but he wants to keep historical data about working operations.

Thus, what I need to do now, is "tell the system" when an item is manteined, then it has to reset the cumulative value while keeping historical data.

Values for the view I created are taken from 2 different tables: Molds and UnmountingOperations. In the latter there are information about which press the mold has been mounted on and the total work done during that operation. I thougt the solution is in the use of triggers, but I'd would like to ask:

What's the best practice to do so?

here you are the scripts created by SqlServer management studio.Sorry but record names are in Italian.
mold table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stampo](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Formato] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[n∞ uscite] [int] NULL,
[Spessore] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Descrizione] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Fornitore] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Stampo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

press table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pressa](
[Numero] [int] NOT NULL,
[Modello] [nchar](10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Pressa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Numero] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

association mold-press for unmounting operations(mq_pressati) is the work amount driver,stands for square meters pressed:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SmontaggioStampi](
[NumeroPressa] [int] NOT NULL,
[IDStampo] [int] NOT NULL,
[DataSmontaggio] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[mq_pressati] [int] NOT NULL,
[Descrizione] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Produzione presse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[NumeroPressa] ASC,
[IDStampo] ASC,
[DataSmontaggio] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmontaggioStampi]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT  [FK_SmontaggioStampi_Pressa] FOREIGN KEY([NumeroPressa])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Pressa] ([Numero])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmontaggioStampi] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SmontaggioStampi_Pressa]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmontaggioStampi]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SmontaggioStampi_Stampo] FOREIGN KEY([IDStampo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Stampo] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SmontaggioStampi] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SmontaggioStampi_Stampo]
GO
```

Comment: Please show us some table definitions. About the business-rules: can a mold be unmounted + mounted, without having been serviced?

Comment: Please provide with table definitions and some code. Is there something missing in the explication.

Comment: sorry guys it's my first post. @wildplasser Yes a mold can be mounted-unmounted several times before being serviced

Comment: It seems logical to *not* reset counters. Just record the {mold_id,date,mileage, ...} with every service, and let the mold->mileage happily tick up. [does the garage reset the mileage to zero when changing the oil for your car ?]

Comment: @wildplasser My problem is that once the mold has been serviced, it will work again for the same amount of material's square meters. the person who's using this application needs to see the mileage since last service. What I could do is to record the service date and then in the view shown up in the application only sum up the amount of work since that date (maybe it's what you meant, if so I apologize, I didn't get it). How can I manage to do that?

Comment: @wildplasser I realized what I was asking. see comments below. thx for taking me on the right way. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for best practices, "avoid triggers like the plague" is the best advice I could give you.

What I've done in a similar situation is to add a column that indicates that a row is now archived.  I used a `datetime` column called `ArchivedDt`.  Normal queries exclude this column like:

```
where  ArchivedDt is null
```

You can even do this in a view.  The hierarchical data is still there, and a specific archive run can be easily undone.

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit, I don't get it. How could I then monitor the amount of work since last service?

Comment: @MarcoBi: The query that monitors the amount of work would contain `where ArchivedDt is null`, so that it only lists new work.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, I think it does. But I was I thinking about adding a new column into the mold table which contains the date when the last manteinance service was executed, and then perform the query which would return the sum of the work performed from that date on, if not null. Would that make sense?

Comment: As far as I can see that's a great choice: you can easily change the MaintenanceDt, and you still keep the entire history.  Another option would be to create a MoldMaintenance table, so you keep a history of maintenance dates as well!

Comment: I opted for my solution. I think it's the simplest so far, and it does pretty well what is meant for. thx for taking me on the right way. cheers